# Интернет магазин на django. Как фильтровать заказы по пользователям?

Tags: django, order

Для проекта я написал account, cart, orders и shop приложения.

order/models:

```
from django.db import models
from shop.models import Product


class Order(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order {}'.format(self.id)

    def get_total_cost(self):
        return sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='order_items',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
```

account/models - пустой

account/views:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import SignUpForm
from orders.models import OrderItem, Order
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            auth_login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def account(request):
    my_orders = Order.objects.all()
    order_items = OrderItem.objects.all()
    return render(request, "accounts/my_acc.html",
                  {"my_orders": my_orders, "order_items": order_items})
```

Как видите в функции

> account

я получаю все заказы, но я не знаю как их отфильтровать.

Я хочу вывести заказы совершенные с данного аккаунта. Очевидно

```
my_orders = Order.objects.all()
order_items = OrderItem.objects.all()
```

выводит вообще все заказы.Собственно и вопрос как реализовать фильтр для Order.objects по аккаунтам?

Comment: У меня примерно такая же проблема как у начинающего! Если у вас получилось решить этот вопрос, то не могли бы вы выложить метод решения с кодом? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @basepas , вот ссылка на тот проект https://github.com/Loctarogar/simple_Django_shop/blob/master/accounts/views.py. Но он был пробный и больше на Django ничего не писал, так что подсказать ничего не смогу. Надеюсь ссылка вам чем то поможет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, создать модель в account\models User c полями first_name last_name и nickname. Дальше сделать проверку в Order зарегистрирован ли пользователь, если у него есть аккаунт брать поля с nickname, first_name, last_name фамилией через ForeignKey с его модели  Account. Если гость -  генерировать рандомный временный nickname. Добавить nick в Order.Meta.ordering и использовать

```
Order.objects.all().filter(nickname= current_account_nickname),
```

где current_account_nickname -  nickname текущего пользователя.
Код расписывать не стал, но думаю алгоритм понятен.
UPD: тупонул немного , с nickname. Можно проверять и сортировать по email.